How to hide / show nav_panel based on user role
I have a shiny app using auth0 authentication and bslib framework, with three nav_panel() and a sidebar.
I want specific panels to be shown or hidden based on the logged-in users role. For example if the role is admin or coach then show Panel 2 and Panel 3, if the role is athlete then hide those two panels. I've tried conditionalPanel() but that doesnt seem to work.
here is a minimal reprex
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_navbar(
  title = "Panel Updates",
  sidebar = sidebar(
    id = "sidebar",
    "Sidebar"),
  nav_panel("Page 1", "Testing"),
  nav_panel("Page 2", "Availability"),
  nav_panel("Page 3", "Team"),
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  session$userData$auth0_info$`/roles` <- "athlete"
  output$role <- reactive({session$userData$auth0_info$`/roles`})
  outputOptions(output, 'role', suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
  observe({print(userRole())})

shinyApp(ui, server)


You can use nav_hide() and nav_show() to control the visibility of the nav_panel()s.
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ROLES <- c("athlete", "coach", "admin")

ui <- page_navbar(
  title = "Panel Updates",
  sidebar = sidebar(
    id = "sidebar",
    "Sidebar",
    radioButtons("role", "Role", choices = ROLES)
  ),
  id = "navbar",
  nav_panel("Page 1", "Testing"),
  nav_panel("Page 2", "Availability"),
  nav_panel("Page 3", "Team"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  role <- reactive({
    session$userData$auth0_info$`/roles` %||% input$role
  })

  observeEvent(role(), {
    if (role() %in% c("admin", "coach")) {
      nav_show("navbar", "Page 2")
      nav_show("navbar", "Page 3")
    } else if (role() == "athlete") {
      nav_hide("navbar", "Page 2")
      nav_hide("navbar", "Page 3")
    } else {
      stop(sprintf("user has unexpected role %s", role()))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


thank you this seemed to work! I thought nav_hide() and nav_show() could only be used in the ui code.
